# Competely removing an <iframe> border

Tags: html, css

Does anybody know how to **completely** remove an iframe border? I am using Firefox 3.x and the iframe is set to **completely occupy** the browser window - `height="100%"` `width="100%"`

I have already set `frameBorder="0"` and `scrolling="no"` but there is some space remaining at the border between the window and the iframe. Is the problem with 100% width and height? Do I need to set more than 100%? By how much?

Comment: where is the iframe? can you show some code?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Do you mean the margin/padding?

In the html file your iframe is displaying try the following CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding 0;
}
```

*edit:*
It could also be similar for your iframe element itself.
If the above doesn't work, in the parent html page try:

```
iframe {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: It worked :) margin=0 on the body worked - I was making some dumb copying error; changes were not being reflected

Comment: Ah, well there you go then :)

Answer (score 8):

This worked for me by disabling border to iframe tags :

```
iframe {
    border:none;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<style>
    html,body, div, iframe{
        height: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        margin: 0; padding: 0;
    }
</style>

<iframe src="http://www.cnn.com" frameborder="no"></iframe>
```

see http://api.fatherstorm.com/test/4159620.php for an example

Comment: It needs to be frameBorder if you want to support < IE7.
Really weird that it's case sensitive, but that's how it is.

Answer (score 0):

```
hspace="0" vspace="0" marginHeight = "0" marginWidth = "0" scrolling= "no" frameBorder="0"                              allowtransparency="true"
```

Answer (score -1):

I use `border: none;` to fix this issue in Firefox.